# Indy 10 TIdHttpServer missing MaxConnectionReply property

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am using Indy10 and have created a Web server using a class derived from **`TIdHttpServer`**.  In my subclass I override the **`DoMaxConnectionsExceeded`** method.  And this seems to be properly firing when **`MaxConnections`** is exceeded.

In earlier Indy versions, at least according to Remy Lebeau's comment [here](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/7/209514.html), there was **`MaxConnectionReply`** property on `TIdHttpServer`.  This could be used to create custom messages if `MaxConnections` was exceeded.  This doesn't seem to be the case with Indy 10.

Is there a way with Indy10 that you can create custom messages when `MaxConnections` is exceeded?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but what you states is not true: In the same thread you point Remy explains that there's no `MaxConnectionReply` property in `TIdHttpServer`, and if you read it again, you'll notice the tread is about Indy 10, not Indy 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the thread you linked to, `MaxConnectionReply` is implemented by `TIdCmdTCPServer`, which `TIdHTTPServer` does not derive from.  Since you are overriding `DoMaxConnectionsExceeded()`, you will have to send your own reply to the client manually, and make sure it is properly HTTP-formatted, for example:

```
procedure TMyHttpServer.DoMaxConnectionsExceeded(AIOHandler: TIdIOHandler);
var
  Html: TIdBytes;
begin
  Html := ToBytes('<html><body>500 - Too many connections</body></html>');
  AIOHandler.WriteLn('HTTP/1.0 500 Too many connections');
  AIOHandler.WriteLn('Content-Type: text/html');
  AIOHandler.WriteLn('Content-Length: ' + IntToStr(Html));
  AIOHandler.WriteLn('Connection: close');
  AIOHandler.WriteLn;
  AIOHandler.Write(Html);
end;
```

Comment: sorry took so long to get back.  Fortunately by increasing the MaxConnections I haven't had the issue.  But I would like to understand.  I set MaxConnections very low, and verify the DoMaxConnectionsExceeded procedure is fired.  Using the example you provide above, I never saw any text.  So instead I used `<html><body>500 - Too many connections</body></html>` and this would show the message.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to include some body data in the HTTP reply.  I have updated my answer.